# How do I pass data from LoginController to my HomeController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to pass my input information (`$request->all()`) from my LoginController to my HomeController. How can I do that? The LoginController is generated by Laravel scaffold.

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use \Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;

class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
    * Override the username method used to validate login
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

HomeController in which `dd($request->all()` returns `[]`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Blog;
use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $blogItems = Blog::all();
        $onlinePlayers = Account::getOnlinePlayers()->count();
        $onlineStaff = Account::getOnlineStaff()->count();
        //return view('home.index', compact('blogItems', 'onlinePlayers', 'onlineStaff'));

        return dd($request->all()); //This returns an empty array
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you want to do that? What data you want to "pass"?

Comment: And how are you going from the one controller to the other?

Comment: Might wanna read about [Old Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#old-input), but what is the use of this?, taken that the login inputs are probably only a password and username, of which the latter you can access through the given User's model.

Comment: The use of it is that I have a page, with 2 modals (Login, Register). So 2 different forms on 1 page. When someone submits for example the Login form and there is an error the error is not visible until you activate the modal. So depending on which form was submitted I want to activate the related modal.

So my idea was to put a hidden field in both with value `register` or `login`. That way I could decide on which form was submitted. Or am I doing this in a way too complicated way and missing the simple way?

Comment: I tried using $errors->has('username') but the problem is that the register form uses this too. So I just need something that passes on to blade when the submit fails. It should be unique for register/login/password-reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick and dirty

The following method is a quick and dirty method. It relies on how Laravel's authentication is designed under the hood. If Laravel changes this in the next version, this may need to change with it.

In your `LoginController`, implement your own `login()` method. You will need to rename the `login()` method provided by the trait because we still want to call it:

```
class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        login as traitLogin
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->flash('form_type', 'login');

        return $this->traitLogin($request);
    }
}
```

In your `RegisterController`, implement your own `register()` method. You will need to rename the `register()` method provided by the trait because we still want to call it:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller 
{
    use RegistersUsers {
        register as traitRegister
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->flash('form_type', 'register');

        return $this->traitRegister($request);
    }
}
```

Now, in your `HomeController`, you can get the type of form that was submitted from the flashed session data.

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $request->session()->get('form_type');

        // the rest of your logic
    }
}
```

#### Cleaner

In contrast to the method above, I would suggest using a hidden form value and a new middleware to process that form value.

This is a little bit cleaner because it doesn't rely on any of the built in Laravel authentication logic. If Laravel changes the name of the traits, the method names, the route actions, or the actual logic used inside the methods, it won't affect how this functionality is designed or how it works.

In your login and register forms, add a new hidden field:

Login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="login" />
```

Register form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="register" />
```

Now, create a middleware that will process this new form element and flash the value to the session.

```
class FlashFormType
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($request->has('form_type')) {
            $request->session()->flash('form_type', $request->input('form_type'));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

From here, you can either add this middleware to the `web` middleware group in `app/Http/Kernel.php` so it is used for all web requests, or you could just add this middleware to the `LoginController` and `RegisterController` constructors so that only they use it.

Once you've assigned the middleware somewhere, update your `HomeController` to access your flashed data:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $request->session()->get('form_type');

        // the rest of your logic
    }
}
```

NB: none of the provided code is tested. treat as pseudo-code.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation I like the clean approach.

Comment: I tested it but it returns null

Comment: @SinanSamet I have updated my answer to change the middleware from a before middleware to an after middleware. See if that gets what you want.

Comment: Still returning null unfortunately

Comment: I also added `use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and changed `handle($request..` to `handle(Request $request..`

Comment: @SinanSamet Both middleware methods seem to work for me. Where did you register the middleware?

Comment: In Kernel `$middlewareGroups = [web] =>  \App\Http\Middleware\FlashFormType::class,..`

Comment: @SinanSamet Since this middleware deals with sessions, you need to make sure it comes after the `StartSession` middleware in the array. Move it after the `StartSession` entry, and you should be good.

Comment: Unfortunately it is already the last one. But it's okay I'll figure it out I probably did something wrong thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get current user, that was authenticated with your login data, then `\Auth:user()` will go the trick. Here is index() of `HomeController`:

```
public function index()
{
    return \Auth::user();
}
```

If you really need input data (actually I cannot imagine the case) , a solution may be to put `request->all()` in session `session(['login_data' => $request->all() ])` and then retrieve it via `session('login_data')`. If you go that way, add this method to your LoginController:

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    session(['login_data' => $request->all() ]);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
        ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This overrides original `sendLoginResponse()` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Then in `HomeController` put this:

```
public function index()
{
    return session('login_data');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The last solution would help but then I would need to add the form type to a session which seems really dirty to me.. I commented on my question maybe that will clarify my reason for this. I will upvote this because it would work but it's not the answer I'm actually going for.

Comment: ok @SinanSamet now i understeand what your want. Yes putting in session is quite dirty. A bit cleaner may be to flash it via `Session::flash('login_error',true);` See more at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/two-forms-on-same-page-list-errors-of-respective-form